# Clarification of meta tag descriptions

Tags: discussion, tags

There seems to be some relationship between the tags:

[wifi](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) and  [wireless](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless)

Should the drop down description of these tags also reference each other?  This may help a user tag a question with a more specific tag.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, [wifi](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) is a subset of [wireless](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) although many people may fail (or just not care) to make that distinction.  However, I'm not sure of any questions that can really be asked under [wireless](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) which would not be better served by a more specific tag like [wifi](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi), [bluetooth](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth), [nfc](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfc), [rfid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rfid), etc.  At least, I can't see too many (if any) questions currently under [wireless](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) which would fit that criteria.

So, I think the question really needs to be:  *"Do we really need the [wireless](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wireless) tag, right now?"*

Comment: I suppose I could retag wireless to the appropriate technology-specific tag.  If it's a good idea, I'll start the process tomorrow.

Comment: @makerofthings7, sure, sounds useful to me!  (And if you spot anything where there's no obvious way to retag it to a more appropriate, specific tag, you could report back.)

Comment: I got [tag:wireless] down to 14 questions before I had to take a break.  There's actually one or two which do sort-of belong in that tag, though.  Mostly to do with generic or proprietary 2.4 GHz tech, like wireless (non-Bluetooth) keyboards/mice etc.  The only reason I say they still belong there is because there's typically no other named standard by which they could be labeled.

Comment: "Right now" is a good point. Originally, it was you that proposed having [tag:wifi], and [tag:wireless] for everything else; I believe that at the time, that decision made sense. *Right now* I think that it does not.

Comment: @AviD I thought the idea sounded familiar.  Kinda like looking at old code, I guess.  Wondering why the heck did I do it that way?

Comment: At the time, I believe the thinking was along the lines "most of our wireless questions will be about wifi; it is unlikely to have a lot of bluetooth questions, or rfid, or..." (I dont think anybody was even talking about nfc yet... )